# google maps api - create line from kml points

Tags: google-maps, kml

I would like to parse points from a kml file (foursquare checkins) in google maps api and use them to create a polyline object (travel path). I know how to create the path but how can I extract the points from the kml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the points from KML using a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)